# Make title of rmarkdown html output bold and divide to 2 lines

Tags: r, r-markdown

I try the following code to justify the main text and make the title bold. I want to choose where the line break is in my long title but when I knit the rmd file non of the style edits happens to the title section.

```
---
title: "my really really really really \n  really really long title"
author: "person"
date: "4/24/2020"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float:
      collapsed: true
      smooth_scroll: false
    toc_depth: 4
    theme: yeti 
    highlight: tango
    code_folding: show
---

<style>
body {
text-align: justify}
title {
font-style: bold}
</style>
```

Comment: Instead of \n, try inserting `<br>` in your title. That should get the title in two lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can format the title in `YAML`. `**text**` is used to make the title bold and `<br>` to break the line.

```
---
title: "**my really really really really <br>  really really long title**"
author: "person"
date: "4/24/2020"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float:
      collapsed: true
      smooth_scroll: false
    toc_depth: 4
    theme: yeti 
    highlight: tango
    code_folding: show
---
```

---

### **my really really really really 
  really really long title**